# Find Pair with Difference less than K with O(n) complexity on average

Tags: algorithm, big-o, hashtable

I have an unsorted array of `n` positive numbers and a parameter `k`, I need to find out if there is a pair of numbers in the array that the difference between than is less than `k` and I need to do so in time complexity of `O(n)` on probable average and in space complexity of `O(n)`.

I believe it requires the use of a universal hash table but I'm not sure how, any ideas?

Comment: Are you working with integers or float values ?

Comment: FTR, that cannot be done in algebraic tree model, since it will mean you can solve Element distinctness problem in `O(n)` by setting `k=0`, which is proven to be Omega(nlogn) problem under this model.

Comment: only integers, but unlimited ones.
I know there is no way with a tree, pretty sure it will use a hash table.

Comment: @amit this problem is Omega(nlogn) with deterministic algorithms, but O(n) in average with randomized ones

Comment: @gdelab Note that I limited this comment to a very narrow computation model (one that does not include hashing, for example), and put it as a comment, since it's not a real answer, but something useful to keep in mind to eliminate solutions that will not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer works even on unbounded integers and floats (doing some assumptions on the nicety of the hashmap you'll be using - the java implementation should work for instance):

1. keep a `hashmap<int, float> all_divided_values`. For each key `y`,
   if `all_divided_values[y]` exists, it will contain a value `v` that
   is in the array such that `floor(v/k) = y`.
2. For each value `v` in the original array `A`, if `v/k` is in  all_divided_values's keys, output `(v, all_divided_values[v/k])`
   (they are distant by less than k). Else, store `v` in
   `all_divided_values[v/k]`
3. Once `all_divided_values` is filled, go through `A` again. For each `v`, test whether `all_divided_values[v/k - 1]` exists, and if so,
   output the pair `(v, all_divided_values[v/k - 1])` if and only if `abs(v-all_divided_values[v/k - 1])<=k`

Inserting in a hashmap is usually (with Java hashmap for instance) `O(1)` in average, so the total time is `O(n)`. But please note that technically this could be false, for instance if your language's implementation does not have a nice strategy about the hashmap.

Comment: the diffrence bitween v and the value created all_divided_values[v/k - 1] might be bigger than k, right?

Comment: Yes, that's why I say "[test] if it makes a suitable pair with v": basically, output the pair iff `abs(v-all_divided_values[v/k - 1])<=k`. I've rephrased my answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

1- Sort the array

2- Calculate the difference between consecutive elements

a) If the difference is smaller than k return that pair

b) If no consecutive number difference yields a value smaller than k, then your array has no pair of numbers such that the difference is smaller than k.

Sorting is O(nlogn), but if you have only Integers of limited size, you can use Counting sort, that is O(n)

Comment: I don't have integers of limited size, they are unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider this way.

The problem can be modeled as this:-

consider each element (considering integer) now you convert them to a range `(A[i]-K,A[i]+K)`

Now you want to check if any of the two intervals overlap.

Interval intersection problem without any sorted ness is not solvable in `O(n)` **(worst case)**. You need to sort them and then inn `O(n)` you can check if hey intersect.

Same goes for your logic. Sort it and find it.

Comment: Please check my answer: I believe it solves the problem. It bypasses the Omega(n log(n)) of interval intersection problem  due to the fact that all intervals have the same size.

Comment: even if some will overlap i can get 2 numbers that differs by 2k instead of one. by the way this can be done in O(n) average (not worse case), by dividing in k and rounding up once and than rounding down, saving all the results and entering them into hash table, than run on it. however as stated it will get 2k diffrences (not all of them) as well.

Comment: @dani39 from your solution it's easy to avoid the 2k difference problem just by saving the exact (undivided) values and comparing them when there is a candidate pair.

Comment: I specifically answered keeping in mind the O(n) worst case...because that is no way possible. That idea comes from the problem mentioned above. Yes this is possible. @dani39 ...I can delete this answer if you think so.